# How to solve Laplace PDE on disk with piecewise boundary condition in Maple?

Tags: maple

Maple 2017.3 on windows, is able to solve Laplace PDE on disk, when the boundary condition `f(theta)` is given as generic function (not defined).

But when I define `f(theta)` using piecewise, it does not solve the PDE for some reason.  Any one knows why? Am I doing something wrong?

Here is MWE showing it can solve the PDE on disk of radius 1, with generic `f(theta)` for the boundary conditions

```
restart;
pde:= diff(u(r,theta),r$2)+1/r*diff(u(r,theta),r) + 1/r^2* diff(u(r,theta),theta$2)=0;
bc:= u(1,theta)=f(theta), 
     u(r,0)=u(r,2*Pi),
     D[2](u)(r,0)=D[2](u)(r,2*Pi);
sol:= pdsolve([pde,bc],u(r,theta)) assuming r<=1  and theta>=0 and theta<2*Pi;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now I changed `f(theta)` above, and gave it a specific function, which is piecewise. Now it does not solve it

```
restart;
f:=theta->piecewise(theta>=0 and theta<=Pi,20,
                    theta>Pi and theta<2*Pi,0);
pde:= diff(u(r,theta),r$2)+1/r*diff(u(r,theta),r) + 1/r^2* diff(u(r,theta),theta$2)=0;
bc:= u(1,theta)=f(theta), 
     u(r,0)=u(r,2*Pi),
     D[2](u)(r,0)=D[2](u)(r,2*Pi);
sol:= pdsolve([pde,bc],u(r,theta)) assuming r<=1 and theta>=0 and theta<2*Pi;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a work around?

For reference, Mathematica 11.2 can solve this:

```
ClearAll[u,r,θ]
pde=D[u[r,θ],{r,2}]+1/r D[u[r,θ],r]+1/r^2 D[u[r,θ],{θ,2}]==0
bc=Piecewise[{{20,0<θ<Pi},{0,Pi<θ<2Pi}}]
sol=DSolve[{pde,u[1,θ]==bc},u[r,θ],r,θ];
sol=sol/.K[1]->n
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So why not obtain the result from `pdsolve` for unassigned `f`, and then substitute the `piecewise`?

```
restart;

pde:= diff(u(r,theta),r$2)+1/r*diff(u(r,theta),r) + 1/r^2* 
diff(u(r,theta),theta$2)=0:
bc:= u(1,theta)=f(theta), 
     u(r,0)=u(r,2*Pi),
     D[2](u)(r,0)=D[2](u)(r,2*Pi):

sol:= rhs(pdsolve([pde,bc],u(r,theta)))
      assuming r<=1 and theta>=0 and theta<2*Pi:

lprint(sol);
   (1/2)*(2*(Sum(r^n*((Int(f(theta)*sin(n*theta), theta = 0 .. 
   2*Pi))*sin(n*theta)+(Int(f(theta)*cos(n*theta), theta = 0 .. 
   2*Pi))*cos(n*theta))/Pi, n = 1 .. infinity))*Pi+Int(f(theta), theta = 0 .. 2*Pi))/Pi

F:=theta->piecewise(theta>=0 and theta<=Pi,20,
                    theta>Pi and theta<2*Pi,0):
```

Below we'll use `subs(f=(F),sol)` for the pde solution with the piecewise `F` substituted for the unassigned name `f`.

Let's compute `sol` at a specific point.

```
sol_spec:=simplify(combine(eval(subs(f=(F),sol),[r=1/2,theta=Pi/3]))):

value(sol_spec): # symbolic summation and symbolic integration

lprint(%);
   (1/2)*((80/3)*Pi+40*arctan((1/5)*3^(1/2)))/Pi

evalf(%);
                      15.45628948

evalf(sol_spec); # numeric summation and numeric integration
                      15.51328895
```

We can resolve the integrals in `sol` and obtain the summation form (as claimed for Mma).

```
T:=subs(f=F,subsindets(sol,specfunc(Int),IntegrationTools:-Split,Pi)):
ans:=simplify(eval(T,Int=int)):

lprint(%);
   10+Sum(20*sin(n*theta)*(r^n-(-r)^n)/(n*Pi), n = 1 .. infinity)
```

Evaluate that at the same specific point as before.

```
ans_spec:=(eval(ans,[r=1/2,theta=Pi/3])):

value(ans_spec): # symbolic summation

lprint(%);
   40/3+20*arctan((1/5)*3^(1/2))/Pi

evalf(%);
                      15.45628948

evalf(ans_spec); # numeric summation
                      15.51328895
```

We can even obtain a closed form for the summation under some conditions on `r` and `theta`.

```
huh:=evalc(subsindets(ans,specfunc(Sum),
                      u->sum(op(u),formal)))
     assuming r>0, r<1, theta>0, theta<Pi:

lprint(huh);
   10+20*arctan(sin(theta)*r/(1-cos(theta)*r))/Pi+20*arctan(sin(theta)*r/(1+cos(theta)*r))/Pi

eval(huh,[r=1/2,theta=Pi/3]):

lprint(%);
   40/3+20*arctan((1/5)*3^(1/2))/Pi

evalf(%);
                      15.45628948
```

Note that there is a bug (already reported) in the combining of pairs of symbolic `arctan` call, which prevents me from simplifying or combining them in `huh` above. This doesn't affect the above results.

Comment: thanks. substituting the function afterwords works. But it should really have worked in the first form as well. But I will use your work around for meanwhile.

Comment: I suspect that PDETools cannot (yet) case-split `piecewise` (or `Heaviside` or `Dirac`).